# How to assess quality of the TSP algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, network, travelling-salesman

I'm trying to develop my own algorithm for solving [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (TSP)
I tested it (in its current state) on the "att48" instance of the [TSPLIB](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/) and got following results:

[image]

As we can see more than 3/4 of results are within 110% of the optimal route length. But in scientific literature they report for over 20 decades that their algorithms solve like 99% of the TSPLIB instances to 1% of the optimal distances (though where are their GIS implementations?!).  So I wonder if there is for example a commonly acceptable threshold for the algorithm output to determinate whether it is garbage or can be used in real life? Or there are exists other means of TSP solver assessment?

Comment: You cannot conclude anything about the general performance of an algorithm when you apply it to only one problem instance! Your plots merely describe the performance of a *randomized* algorithm on a single dataset.  (Because it is randomized, it produces a distribution of outputs rather than a single unvarying result.) If you would like to address the performance overall then you need to replicate this study for a large number of varied inputs.

Comment: @whuber, of course it should be tested on more problems (and it will be after performance tweaks), but the question remains - is there a threshold to distinguish good and bad algorithms for a problem of the given size? I didn't catch your point about randomisation - most of heuristic algorithms are randomisation-based. Even if output is always the same we can say that 100% of results are within n% of the optimal length.

Comment: The points about randomization were made to explain the varying nature of your results and to distinguish variation in the application to *one* problem from variation in the application to *a suite* of problems. There cannot possibly be a universal threshold, as you ask, because whether an algorithm is suitable for you depends on much more than how closely it approaches the optimum: it depends on the costs of implementing and running the algorithm, what your accuracy needs are, and the consequences when the algorithm produces a suboptimal result.

Comment: @whuber, I found a methodology - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found [a recent article](http://www.jtacs.org/archive/2013/1/4/JTACS_2013_01_04.pdf) where they tested and compared several TSP algorithms. They made tested algorithms find their solutions under 100 seconds time limits for several datasets. For my luck 'att48' was amongst them. Here is one of comparison tables (distanced are divided by 100):

[image]

So I have a good news for myself - my solutions were found under 100 seconds (85-95) of the real time (not CPU time), and the only algorithm in this table that outperforms mine for the 'att48' is simulated annealing.

Comment: This is nice for you--but it does not appear to answer the question you posed! It is not valid to take such a table of comparisons as being any kind of evidence of "commonly acceptable thresholds."

Comment: @whuber, the question is in the title - 'How to assess quality of the TSP algorithm?' _Threshold_ was my hypothesis of quality assessment.

Comment: So you didn't really mean it when you concluded your post with "I wonder if there is a commonly acceptable threshold for the algorithm output to determinate whether it is garbage or can be used in real life?"

Comment: @whuber, again - treshold was _my_ idea of the TSP algorithm assessment. I'm not bold enough to think that my ideas are [always] the best.

Comment: I am not challenging your ideas: I am merely asking you, in my role as moderator, to make sure your question is sufficiently clear to be well understood by your readers.  I have already commented on issues that I think are important concerning the question you *seem* to have asked, but only you really know the question you *intended* to ask.

Comment: @whuber, I edited question to make it more clear.